# Block a file without blocking the Ruby process on failures

Tags: ruby

Hello I am trying to lock a file by using `file.flock(File::LOOK_EX)`

The problem it is blocking the app if it unable to block the file.

The `rescue` does not help either.

Is there any way to tell `flock` to fail if it cannot lock the file on the first try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `LOCK_NB` constant:

```
file.flock(File::LOOK_EX | File::LOCK_NB)
```

That will prevent the operation from blocking.

Comment: mm, did not see `NB` constant in the book, trying